# Lotus leaves dying

Tags: flowers

These are my first lotus plants and I dont know much about them. I have grown them from seeds. Roots are in a container filled with soil,organic compost and gravel. This pot is inside a big container filled with water. Also its a rainy season here with temp ranging between 25 degree celsius to 30 degree celsius.

From couple of days leaves started to rot. Is this normal behaviour for lotus? Or i am doing something wrong ? How frequently i should change water in the container? I last changed it around 4-5 days back.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could be overwatering.

Comment: ;)... Have you seen fungus gnats on the leaves at all?

Comment: Do you have a recirculating pump?

Comment: So this is in a large pot of some kind?  What kind of water are you using?  Have you considered putting fish in this water?  The lilies should keep the water from overheating.  What have you added to this system?  How are the roots and soil doing in their pots in the pot?  I've done this so many times without fungus problems.  Is this pot out of doors??

Comment: I wish I would read the questions more closely.  Have you fertilized at all?  What kind of compost?  Was this compost decomposed or raw?  Do change out the water or better just stick a hose in your system and allow it to overfill and replace some of the water.  Do this every day in lieu of recirculating.  This adds oxygen to the water.

Comment: @stormy no pump..usually i change water every week..compost is vermi compost.. not additional fertilizer yet. Should i remove rotted leaves ?

Comment: Adding fish will improve health of lotus?

Comment: Yes remove dead leaves/debris.  This is not a natural system so you get to do most of the control.  Yes, fish are fun and kits for their artificial ponds or aquariums will help you with pH and chemistry.  All plants need added balanced fertilizer.  Compost adds a few chemical elements and compounds but is not a balanced fertilizer.  It is necessary to include into your fertilizer calculations, however.  What is your water source?  Tap water? Have you ever had aquariums?  Also, a pliecostomous (sp) or a Plieco...ancient looking fish that gets along with most all other fish.  It sucks up algae.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect [black spot fungus](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/plant-problems/disease/black-spot-fungus.htm) and you have a lot of necrotic lesions on those leaves sadly.

Treat with Neem oil initially.  And then try a fungicide if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem and most of the forums did not help.

Finally I did the following

1. I used purified water to obviate chemicals in the water.
2. I did not embedded the seed in the mud but gently pressed it on the surface of the mud so that the seed was exposed.
3. I allowed the seed to take root naturally.

The plant is flourishing.

Hope this helps u guys.